# Wacom penabled tablet pc okay in 10.10 not 14.04.2 lts

Tags: lubuntu, 14.10, touchscreen, wacom

I am trying to get a decent distro working on my sister's 8 year old toshiba satelllite r10.
She used it in tablet mode with XP until it ground to a halt. I have tried various lightweight distros (puppy, tinycore and lubuntu 14.10) but none recognised the Wacom digitiser screen.The system has only 400MB and a pentium M.

I found refs to ubuntu 10.10 working okay and yes I was able to use a live booting Linux Format cover disk.

My question is what is the difference between 10.10 and 14.04 (I tried that too) that loses the knowledge of the tablet?
I originally suspect X server configuration.

Meanwhile I will prepare a separate question about WINE and powerpoint 2007. WORD and Excel work okay.

I remember being able to install RedHat 5.2 (1998) on 1GB partition alongside Win98 on a Sony Vaio laptop (233MHz) with only 64MB RAM. What happened?

Dr.Skids